# Group elements of order 2 whose product has order n.

Tags: group-theory

I am looking at the following problem:

> For every positive integer $n$ construct a group containing two elements $g,h$ such that $|g|=2$, $|h|=2$, and $|gh|=n$

Here $|g|$ denotes the order of $g$.

I get that for $n>1$ we can take the dihedral group, with say $s$ and $sr$ where $r$ is rotation and $s$ is reflection, as $s^2 = e$ and $srsr = srr^{n-1}s = e$, so they both have order $2$. Also $ssr = r$ clearly has order $n$. But I do not get how this is possible for $n=1$. In particular this would mean $g^2=h^2=e$ and as $|gh|=1$ we have $gh=e$. Setting $g^2 = gh$ we find $g=h$, so these elements cannot be distinct. Or is that the point? I.e., can we just take $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $g=h=1$.

Comment: Yes, although (being very pedantic), if $g = h$, then $g$ and $h$ are one element, not two. But that's the author of the problem's problem, not your problem $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct!

We can define the group $G$ using the [presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)

$$P=\langle g,h\mid g^2, h^2, (gh)^n\rangle.$$

Let $k=gh$. Then $h=g^{-1}k$ and so, by Tietze transformations, $G$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
G&\cong\langle g,h,k\mid g^2, (g^{-1}k)^2, k^n, k=gh\rangle\\
&\cong \langle g,k\mid g^2, gkgk, k^n\rangle\\
&\cong\langle g,k\mid g^2, k^n, gkg=k^{-1}\rangle,
\end{align}$$

which is [well-known for being a presentation for the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ of order $2n$.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_Group/Group_Presentation)

---

If $n=1$, then

$$\begin{align}
D_2&\cong\langle g,k\mid g^2, k^n, gkg=k^{-1}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle g,k\mid g^2, k, gkg=k^{-1}\rangle,\\
&\cong\langle g\mid g^2, 1, g^2=1\rangle\\
&\cong \langle g\mid g^2\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_2.
\end{align}$$

But we have to be careful: it specifies *two* elements $g,h$ of order $2$, so perhaps $n>1$, for precisely the reason you describe!

---

The area of mathematics that deals with questions like these is called [combinatorial group theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_group_theory).